# printf печатет только три первых символа строки

Tags: c, строки, printf

Есть код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

bool strbegin(const char *, const char *);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) 
{
    FILE * src_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char * buf_str  = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char)); 

    while (fgets(buf_str, sizeof(buf_str), src_file)) {
        if (strbegin(buf_str, "#"))
            printf("This string begin with '#': \n%s", buf_str);
    }

    fclose(src_file);
    return 0;
}

bool strbegin(const char * _str, const char * _begin)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(_begin); ++i) {
        if (_begin[i] != _str[i])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Этот код печатает строку, которая начинается с символа **#**.

Содержимое файла:

```
// ex1.ar
#include <stdio>
```

Вот вывод программы:

```
This string begin with '#': 
#in
```

Если вместо

`printf("This string begin with '#': \n%s", buf_str);`

Написать

```
printf("This string begin with '#': \n");
printf("%s", buf_str);
```

Результат тот же. Причем вне условия `if` строки печатаются полностью. Функция `strbegin` ошибок не содержит - проверял. Никак не могу понять из-за чего ошибка, вроде бы все правильно.

Компилирую так:
`clang-3.8 src/main.c -o bin/main -Wall -pedantic`

Запускаю:
`./bin/main example/ex1.ar`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка в использовании `sizeof`.  `sizeof(buf_str)`  возвращает размер указателя , то есть 4 байта.

```
  fgets(buf_str, 1024, src_file);
```